# MacOS cannot run nginx

Tags: macos, nginx

When I run nginx on my MacOS.

```
➜  nginx nginx
```

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/nginx
  Reason: image not found
[1]    10170 abort      nginx

Comment: It depends on OpenSSL, like the error tells you.  You can `brew install openssl` to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Please start by installing HomeBrew http://brew.sh/. It is a package manager for MacOS that allows to easily install various Unix applications.
MacOS will prompt you to first install Xcode Command Line Tools (unless you have them already).
After installation, the following command, if necessary, will tell you how to complete the installation:

```
brew doctor
//Then updates all packages with:
brew update
brew upgrade
//Then Install Nginx
brew install nginx
// Then automatically launch Nginx at startup with:
sudo cp /usr/local/opt/nginx/*.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem for a bit, but when I ran

```
brew uninstall nginx
```

and then

```
brew install nginx
```

It reinstalled properly and I was able to run it without getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. Please use it after having uninstalled Nginx using this command:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.25.3
```

Comment: *What* worked for you? We can not know what you are relating to, because the listed order of answers is changeable. Also, please use comments for additional info or up-voting for general confirmation.